# Using MSUnit to run Selenium UI tests on the current solution

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I have a VS2012 solution that consists of class library projects, unit/integration test projects and a web site project.

Using this http://bipinkarms.com/wp/automated-ui-tests-with-selenium-and-mstest/ as a guide, I am able to setup a test to start chrome and script some Chrome commands, but I can't figure out how to run them against my web project.

IE, the first action of my test should be to build by solution and launch the web project, THEN execute some of my UI test code against the web project (keeping in mind that the build in web server port number could change).

If my project isn't running, I don't have anything to test against.

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I have found to do this is to setup IIS on your machine to point a virtual directory back to your project and as long as IIS is up and running your tests will succeed.

You can set this up on your web project in the web tab of the properties dialog.  Select the `Use Local IIS Web Server` option.  The first time you do this, you can click the `Create Virtual Directory` button to create the directory for you.